# Change in variable triggers an event

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Is triggering an event via a change in variable possible? For example.

This would trigger the event

```
Dim t As Integer
Dim Fire As Boolean

Private Sub Test
t = 0
Fire = True
IIf Fire, t=1, t=2
End sub
```

In the event handler

```
Select Case t
    Case 0
       'Do something
    Case 1
       'Do something            
    Case 2
       'Do something
    Case 3
       'Do something
    ...
```

Google brings up Event handlers, and using class modules but I am unable to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is possible. However, you'll need an Object Oriented approach.
You first need to define a class that raises the events you wish to hook into. Secondly you'll need a class that actually handles the event, since you can not use event handlers in a regular module.
Thirdly, in your regular module you can then just use these classes.

Here's a simple example:
Create a class module named "ClassWithEvent". Place the following code:

```
Public Event VariableChange(value As Integer)
Private p_int As Integer
Public Property Get value() As Integer
    value = p_int
End Property
Public Property Let value(value As Integer)
    If p_int <> value Then RaiseEvent VariableChange(value) 'Only raise on actual change.
    p_int = value
End Property
```

Next, create the class that can handle the events raised by this class.
Name this Class Module "ClassHandlesEvent". Place the following code in it:

```
Private WithEvents SomeVar As ClassWithEvent
Private Sub SomeVar_VariableChange(value As Integer) 'This is the event handler.
    Select Case value
        Case 1:
            MsgBox "here, 1!"
        Case 2:
            MsgBox "here, 2!"
        Case Default:
            'Do Nothing
    End Select
End Sub
Public Property Get EventVariable() As ClassWithEvent
    Set EventVariable = SomeVar
End Property
Public Property Let EventVariable(value As ClassWithEvent)
    Set SomeVar = value
End Property
```

Next, in a regular module, instantiate your ClassWithEvent and pass this one as a property to the class that handles them.

```
Sub test()
    Dim var As ClassHandlesEvent
    Dim tst As ClassWithEvent

    Set var = New ClassHandlesEvent
    Set tst = New ClassWithEvent
    var.EventVariable = tst

    tst.value = 2 'A messagebox saying "Here, 2!" will pop-up
End Sub
```

Comment: An enhancement I might suggest would be to raise the event only if the variable changes.  Currently you would get an event if you set the value to 2 again.

Comment: @BrianMStafford you're right. Amended the code to check if the value is not equal.

Comment: My friend, I Sincerely thank you for your detailed answer and for you taking time to show me this. It will take me a bit to follow as to what is going on step by step. Your answer worked flawless from what I can tell.

Comment: More than welcome. A great resource for getting acquainted with Classes and Objects in VBA for Excel is Chip Pearson's introduction, here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx He also has written a nice introduction to events here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/events.aspx
Also, stepping through the execution with F8 will give a lot of clarity.

Comment: Very nice. You have a little mixup with `p_int` vs. `p_t` in the first code block.

Comment: So, if I wanted to listen for changes on the databodyrange of a public ListObject (table), than am I creating the ListObject as a class or am I setting tst.value = ListObject? How do I use this to listen for changes to a ListObject's databodyrange?

Comment: @user117294 You'd need to check the events of the ListObject to see if you can just event sink it and use that directly. If that doesn't work, you can build a custom class against the range it uses, or just use Worksheet_Change event and check the intersection of the databodyrange and the target parameter of the worksheet_change event.