# Excel VBA - Return Control to Calling Method when the called method has already called another method

Tags: excel, vba, oop, error-handling, event-handling

I have a model simluation coded in Excel VBA.  It is built inside of a class module named "ChemicalRelease".  There is another Class module named "UniversalSolver" which works to optimize parameters of the ChemicalRelease.

While running different simulations, universalSolver will sometimes use a combination of parameters that goes outside of the modeling bounds of the application.  It is difficult to determine the true modeling boundaries as it is based on multiple combinations of parameters.

An instance of UniversalSolver will create a set of input parameters and instantiate ChemicalRelease to run a model as specified.  Inside of ChemicalRelease, the flow works within several methods such as "setden" which may call other methods to perform their calculation.  For example, "setden" may call "tprop" to determine thermodynamic properties, and "tprop" may in turn call a function to iteratively solve for a value.

At any point within any of these methods, the model may determine that the combination of input parameters cannot be solved.  The current configuration notifies me of the issue thru a msgbox and stops the program, bringing it into debug mode.

I would like to make use of an event handler that will set a value of an instance of a handler that will stop calculations within "ChemicalRelease", set the instance to "Nothing" and return control to "UniversalSolver", directly after the line where "ChemicalRelease" was instantiated and called for modeling.

serveral google searches, and none point to a way to return control to "UniversalSolver".

'event handler code:  credit to [Change in variable triggers an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389548/change-in-variable-triggers-an-event)

"ClassWithEvent" class

```
Public Event VariableChange(value As Integer)
Private p_int As Integer
Public Property Get value() As Integer
    value = p_int
End Property
Public Property Let value(value As Integer)
    If p_int <> value Then RaiseEvent VariableChange(value) 'Only raise on 
    actual change.
    p_int = value
End Property
```

"ClassHandlesEvent" class

```
Private WithEvents SomeVar As ClassWithEvent
Private Sub SomeVar_VariableChange(value As Integer) 'This is the event 
    handler.

    'line here to return control to "UniversalSolver" instance, out of 
     "ChemicalRelease" instance, regardless of how many methods have to be 
     returned out of within ChemicalRelease.

End Sub
Public Property Get EventVariable() As ClassWithEvent
    Set EventVariable = SomeVar
End Property
Public Property Let EventVariable(value As ClassWithEvent)
    Set SomeVar = value
End Property
```

"Globals" Module
'Globally set instances for ClassHandlesEvent and ClassWithEvent

```
Global VAR As ClassHandlesEvent
Global TST As ClassWithEvent
```

"UniversalSolver" class

```
Public Sub initialize()

    Set VAR = New ClassHandlesEvent
    Set TST = New ClassWithEvent
    VAR.EventVariable = TST

End Sub

Public Sub solve()

     Do 'iterate through potential input parameters

         Set m_chemRelease = New ChemicalRelease

         m_chemRelease.initialize 'initializes and launches modeling

     Loop until satisfied

End Sub
```

"ChemicalRelease" class

```
Public Sub initialize(modelParamsSheet As Worksheet)

    Set m_modelParamsSheet = modelParamsSheet
    Call readModelInputsAndSetProperties(0)


End Sub

Private Sub readModelInputsAndSetProperties(inNum As Integer)

    'set all properties and launch modeling
    Call setjet(0)

End Sub

Private Sub setjet(inInt As Integer)

    'lots of math.  

    call tprop(tpropsInputDict)

    'lots more math.



End Sub

Private Sub tprop(inDict as Scripting.Dictionary)

    'more math.

    'check for convergence

    If check > 0.00001 Then

        'failed convergence
        'trigger event to exit ChemicalRelease Instance and return control 
         to UniversalSolver instance

        TST.value = 2


    End If

    'more math.

    Call limit()

End Sub

Private Sub limit()

    'more math.

    'check for sign

    If fa * fb > 1 Then

        'failed convergence
        'trigger event to exit ChemicalRelease Instance and return control 
         to UniversalSolver instance

        TST.value = 2


    End If

    'more math.

End Sub
```

Expected results are to have an event which can be triggered at any location within the project that will return control to UniversalSolver as if I was stating "exit sub" from within ChemicalRelease.initialize.  However, I cannot find a valid method for this.

Answer (score 0):

Error handling in the calling function works for all called functions.  However, the "resume" command is required to take VBA out of error-handling mode.  Per the code below, flow is returned to normal mode at the "endoffor" label in the calling function.

```
errcatch:
Err.Clear

On Error GoTo errcatch
Resume endoffor '
```